# HTML: Why underscore in _blank vs another char

Tags: html

Does anyone know why the underscore in _blank was the chosen character.

I understand _blank opens up a new windows/tab each time. But why _ was chosen?

Comment: To those of you who hair-trigger jump on the "opinion-based" close button, please consider that this question might actually have an objective answer. I don't know of it personally, but it's entirely possible there's a W3C document out there or some other primary source that objectively justifies this design decision.

Comment: The underscore goes waaaay back to the earliest days of HTML. Someone may be able to dig up a discussion but it would be back from the 90's.

Comment: I re-opened this question because the other question that this was closed as a dupe of doesn't explain the "why", just what was formally selected.

Comment: The reason is that target="blank" would be used for for example a frame with name="blank" - so to not conflict with otherwise reasonable names, an unlikely prefix was chosen

Comment: @mplungjan That's fine, but the OP is asking why the underscore character  versus some other character, like @

Comment: As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22289844/why-the-target-property-in-link-has-an-underscore)

Comment: @mplungjan The question is not "why a prefix". The question is "why underscore as opposed to, say, dollar sign". I mean, Java uses $ for the exact same purpose: avoiding conflict with user-defined names

Comment: And `@` was already taken. `$` could be used but wasn't for good reasons ignored by JS. I hate writing `\`$${amount}\``

Comment: This is not a question about programming and likely opinion based if someone can dig up etymology. So in any case not a good fit for SO